# replace string using UNIX commands

Tags: unix

I want to replace the first occurrence of search pattern with something and rest with something else as:

```
aaa
bbb
ccccc
country
dddd
country
frrffr4
grtgt
gthth
country
dddrr
```

here I want **country** to be replaced. First occurence of countryshould be **my_country** and rest of the occurences with **our_country** as:

```
aaa
bbb
ccccc
my_country
dddd
our_country
frrffr4
grtgt
gthth
our_country
dddrr
```

Is there any command to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk 'BEGIN {r="my_country"} /country/ {print r; r="our_country"; next} {print}'
```